# toggle fontawesome icons using vue / nuxt js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to toggle this fontawesome icons

```html
<i class="fa-solid fa-heart"></i> //when active
<i class="fa-regular fa-heart"></i>  //when not active
```

This is my code

```html
<i class="fs-5" 
        role="button" 
        @click="!active" 
        :class="[active ? 'fa-solid fa-heart' : 'fa-regular fa-heart'] "
        ></i>
```

my script

```js
data() {
    return {
      active: false,
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set active to false/true like `active=!active` and refactor `fa-heart` class:

```html
<i class="fs-5" 
        role="button" 
        @click="active = !active" 
        :class="['fa-heart',active ? 'fa-solid' : 'fa-regular'] "
        ></i>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like this:

```html
<button :class="active ? 'fa-solid' : 'fa-regular'" class="fs-5 fa-heart" style="appearance: none;" @click="active = !active" />
```